# MySQL com Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

Tenho um projeto em que preciso utilizar o MySQL como banco de dados e EF6 com a abordagem de CODE FIRST.

Instalei o MySql.Data.Entity 6.9.9 e o EntityFramework 6.1.3

Meu app.config está da seguinte forma:

```
<configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
    connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=MyContext;uid=user;password=***"/>
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
<providers>
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
<remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
<add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Quando executo o update-database recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> Target database is: 'MyContext' (DataSource: .\SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).

O VS2015 está criando o banco no SQLEXPRESS, o que preciso alterar para utilizar o MySQL?

Comment: app.confg? é windows forms sua aplicação ? você esta pondo a sua connectionString no lugar correto ?:

Comment: Na verdade é um web MVC, em multi camadas. A camada de dados é um class library. A conexão está no lugar certo.

Comment: ok, mas acredito que a aplicação (class library) utilize o web.config do projeto de UI e não dela mesma.

Comment: Na minha solution ainda não tinha colocado a aplicação MVC. Obrigado pela dica